# How does Halo 5 Guardians Warzone scoring work?

Tags: halo-5-guardians

It's well known that the first team to 1000 points wins, and A.I. bosses are worth points that are displayed next to their name.

What **other** specific events earn points?  And how many specifically?

Answer (score 3):

Spartan Kills = 1 point.

AI Kills = 0 points.

Boss AI Kills = The value next to their name, anywhere from 25 to 150 points.

Neutral Base Capture = 0 points.

Enemy Base Capture = 0 points.

Holding bases = 1 point per base every 5 seconds.

It seems the way to win Warzone is go after AI bosses as a top priority, as nothing else really gives rewards besides the obvious spartan kills.

Unfortunately the source is my own experience as I haven't found any confirmed data posted elsewhere yet.